# indexedDB correct usage

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm experimenting with indexedDB. Now everything is like asynchronous and that hurts my brain a lot.

I created an object like this:

```
var application = {};
application.indexedDB = {};
application.indexedDB.db = null;

application.indexedDB.open = function() {

   var dbName = "application";
   var dbVersion = 1;

   var openRequest = indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion);

   openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {

      console.log("Upgrading your DB (" + dbName + ", v" + dbVersion + ")...");

      var thisDB = e.target.result;

      if (!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains("journal")) {
         thisDB.createObjectStore(
            "journal", 
            {keyPath: "id"}
         );
      }
   }

   openRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
      console.log("Opened DB (" + dbName + ", v" + dbVersion + ")");
      application.indexedDB.db = e.target.result;
   }

   openRequest.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log("Error");
      console.dir(e);
   }
};
```

Now I am able to open the dbconnection with `application.indexedDB.open()`. Now I added another function to my Object:

```
application.indexedDB.addItemToTable = function(item, table) {

    var transaction = application.indexedDB.db.transaction([table], "readwrite");
    var store = transaction.objectStore(table);

    //Perform the add
    var request = store.add(item);

    request.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("Error", e.target.error.name);
        //some type of error handler
    }

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        console.log("Woot! Did it");
    }
};
```

My instruction-sequence extended like this:

1. `application.indexedDB.open()`
2. `application.indexedDB.addItemToTable(item, "journal")`

But this doesn't work. Because the open-Instruction is asynchronous the `application.indexedDB.db`is not yet available when i call it in the addItemToTable-Function.
How does a Javascript-Developer solve this?

I was following this tutorial here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-indexeddb--net-34673 and now I have some problems with those examples.

For example he creates the HTML-Output directly in the "onsuccess"-Part (in the "Read More Data" Section) . In my eyes this is bad coding because the view has nothing to do with the db-reading part.. isn't it? but then comes my question. how the heck can you return something in the "onsuccess"-Part?
Adding callbackfunctions is somewhat complicated. Especially when i want to read some data and with that resultset get some more data. It's very complicated to describe what i mean.
I made a little fiddle - maybe it clarifies things.. -- http://jsfiddle.net/kb8nuby6/

Thank you

Comment: just for your information there is a library called IDBWrapper that wraps the complexity and provides a convenient way to deal with IndexedDb. find out more: http://jensarps.github.io/IDBWrapper/

Comment: i would recommend a tool to use on top of indexDB so you don't have to deal with as much low-level coding. pouchDB is a good one, or even the jQeury one. You could also look into creating promise wrappers that will allow you to code in a more conventional top-down manner.

Comment: ConstraintError means that you're trying to add data with an existing key. Try to rename your DB and it doesn't give you any errors

Comment: Thank you for your comments! The frameworks you suggested (pouchDB and IDBWrapper) look very promising. I will check them out soon! And as @Josh said in his post - i'll practice in asynchronous js.. It seems there's a lack of knowledge there.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use someone else's extra program. You will need to learn about asynchronous javascript (AJAX) before using indexedDB. There is no way to avoid it. You can learn about AJAX without learning about indexedDB. For example, look at how XMLHttpRequest works. Learn about setTimeout and setInterval. Maybe learn about requestAnimationFrame.  If you know nodejs stuff, review process.nextTick.  Learn about how functions are first class. Learn about the idea of using a callback function. Learn about continuation passing style.

You will probably not get the answer you are looking for to this question. If anything, this is a duplicate of the several thousand other questions on stack overflow about asynchronous programming in javascript. It is not even that related to indexedDB. Take a look at some of the numerous other questions about asynchronous js.

Maybe this gets you started:

```js
var a;
setTimeout(function() { a = 1; }, 10);
console.log('The value of a is %s', a);
```

Figure out why that did not work. If you do, you will be much closer to finding the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I commonly adopted is wait all database operations until connected. It is similar concept to `$.ready` in jQuery.

You will find that as the app get age, you have many schema versions and need to upgrade data as well. A lot of logic in database connection itself.

You can use callback queue, if you need to use database before ready. Here is snippet from Google analytics on [commend queue](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced):

```
// Creates an initial ga() function.  The queued commands will be executed once analytics.js loads.
i[r] = i[r] || function() {
  (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
},
```

Basically, you will execute these callbacks once database is connected.

I highly recommend to check out my own library, [ydn-db](https://github.com/yathit/ydn-db). It has all these concepts.